# Object.assign alters original object values

Tags: javascript, deep-copy

I am running into this issue, when i use `Object.assign()` previous value getting overridden.

```js
var blueprint = {
 name: {
   first: "Default first name",
    last: "Default last name"
  }
};

var person1 = Object.assign( {}, blueprint );

console.log( blueprint.name.first ); // Gives me "Default first name"

person1.name.first = "John";

console.log( blueprint.name.first ); // Gives me "John"
console.log( blueprint.name.last ); // Gives me "Default last name"
```

Question is how can i override person1.name.first while keep my blueprint safe?

Comment: The question is missleading. By reading it I though that just using the function resulted in the source object being mutated. Please reformulate. Btw, the problem is relatated to the fact that Object.assign does not make a deep copy of the source object

Comment: You need to make a copy of the `.name` object as well, i.e. `person1.name = Object.assign({}, blueprint.name);`

Comment: You have to deep copy the source objects like this `var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blueprint));`.